# How to pass user sessions from ionic application to and inapp browser index page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm currently working on an ionic project which require me to open a website from an my ionic application using ionic inappbrowser.
The problem is that the website requires a login, which i want to bypass and pass the login/register details from my ionic app to the website so that my users will not need to login on the website again.

Comment: you can pass auth token in the url and check in on website.

Comment: Kindly explain more Thank you

Comment: What do u mean by token, how do I pass it. Kindly help explain more

Comment: how are you managing your authentication in your application?? is there any auth token for your logged in users? if yes then you could pass it into your url.

Comment: Know how the website u wanna login to, logs users in. Usually after u enter the creds the backend gives the frontend a token and then the frontend code LogsIn with the token. U need to get that token and pass it to the website's the login function and you will be logged in. Else Brute Force it and use Web Scraping